# find min max of function on unit ball

Tags: optimization

$g(a,b,c)=3a-2b+c$, B is a closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$.  Find the max/min of g on B.  What is the behavior of $g$ on the open unit ball, and the boundary of the unit ball?

I think the unit ball can be defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.  Should I minimize $g$ on this surface?  how do I discuss the behavior of $g$ on the open ball, and the boundary?

Comment: By Lagrange multipliers (or intuition), the max/min will be at one of the two points where the line $t(3,-2,1), t\in \mathbb R$ intersects the unit sphere.

Comment: @WilliamStagner Thank you.  I am still unsure what the question is looking for when it asks about behavior on $B^O$ and boundary of B.  Any clues?

Comment: FWIW, the closed unit ball is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1$, the open unit ball is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \lt 1$.